# How to pass g:textfiled value from GSP to controller in grails as part of params

Tags: grails, gsp

I am trying to pass the value of a g:textfield to controller on click of a link.but i get null in controller . Below is the code:

GSP code:

```
<label class="col-md-2">Profile Name :</label>
<g:textField type="text" name="searchbox"  class="form-control" />
<g:link action="profileSearch" id="searchlnk1" params="[searchboxval:"${searchbox}"]">search</g:link>
```

when i access the value of serachbox in controller, i get null. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

```
params="[searchboxval:"${searchbox}"]"
```

will not pull the value from the form field - GString expressions like `${searchbox}` are evaluated on the server side while rendering the form, not on the browser after the form has been filled in.

You need to use a proper form rather than a link, more like:

```
<g:form action="profileSearch" id="searchlnk1">
  <label class="col-md-2">Profile Name :</label>
  <g:textField type="text" name="searchboxval"  class="form-control" />
  <g:submitButton value="search"/>
</g:form>
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it using link?

Comment: Thanks a lot of the clarification

Comment: @GrailsTest only if you use JavaScript to read the value out of the text field when the link is clicked.

Comment: Can you let me know how to do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: @GrailsTest your use of `col-md-2` suggests you're using Bootstrap CSS, so if it's just a matter of the appearance then you can [style the button to look like a link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-options) via a CSS class (`class="btn btn-link"`).